# Condition under which a bounded linear operator from a subspace can be extended

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, banach-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and let $M$ be a subspace of $X$. Let $T:M\to Y$ be a bounded linear operator. We know that if $M$ is dense in $X$, then there exists a unique bounded linear operator $S:X\to Y$ such that $S\vert_M=T$ and $\|S\|=\|T\|$. I have got somewhere (that I can not recall) that if $M$ is not dense, then also there exists a bounded linear operator $S:X\to Y$ such that $S\vert_M=T$ if and only if closure of $M$ is complemented in $X$.

Could anyone please give me a reference for that? Also, in that case can we expect that $\|S\|=\|T\|$? Of course, I understand that the uniqueness can not be expected.

Comment: There is nothing so simple, see  [Zippin, Extension of Bounded Linear Operators](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~zippin/exten.ps) and [Saccoman, On the extension of linear operators](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/IJMMS/28/10621.pdf).

Comment: If the closure of $M$ is complemented, then then there is a projection $\pi:X\to \overline M$ and you can extend $T$ by taking $\tilde T=T\circ\pi$. On the other hand if $\overline M$ is not complemented then $1_M:M\to M$ does not extend to $X$.